# Как сделать остановку страницы при прокрутке за 90px до якоря?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Вопрос в следующем:

Есть страница с фиксированным навигационным блоком сверху.
Сайт одностраничный и все пункты навигации ведут на якоря
на этой же странице.

Дело в том, что при переходе по ссылке блок, в котором
стоит якорь, заезжает под навигационный блок. Высота
навигационного блока 90рх.

Как можно сделать, чтобы ссылка вела не на конкретный
якорь, а страница останавливалась за 90рх до якоря?

Или может есть другой способ, чтобы якорь не заезжал
под навигацию?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Якоря пустые? Тогда надо дать им стиль `position: relative; top:-90px`

Comment: Якоря пустые, поэтому этот способ не подходит. Он работает только в случае, если в якоре что-то есть.

Comment: Мне так не кажется: [работающий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/W2par/).

Comment: Ну так там и получается, что если якорь имеет какой-то вложенный в себя элемент, то у Вас страница останавливается на нём, а если якорь пустой, то ссылка как будто игнарирует его и останавливается на тексте сразу после якоря. У Вас там также с пустым якорем блок навигации находит на текст.

Comment: Находит, потому, что я не потрудился сделать аккуратно. Даже у пустого html элемента есть позиция, на которой скролл и остановится. Включайте голову уже : )

Comment: Не знаю, я уже целый день пытаюсь включить голову, никак не могу сделать. А Ваш пример я у себя на компе проверил.

Comment: Чуть обновил: http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/W2par/
У вас пример этот работает? По ссылке.

Comment: Нет, не работает. В Macromedia Dr. вижу, что якорь выше текста находится. Но ссылка не на нём останавливает. На якоре только при его наполнении.

Comment: Ладно уж, поставлю в якоре точку размером 1рх и не буду мучаться. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: Способ с name устарел. Надо использовать id элемента.